# Wordpress Custom Post Type Archive Not Loading

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, custom-post-type

I have setup a custom post type of 'Games' in WordPress 3.7.1.  Everything is working well, I have created several items of this post type and created/assigned categories to them.  The query to display the posts from this CPT works as it should and my custom single page (single-game.php) works too.

However, when I create archive-game.php, WordPress loads the default archive.php file and pagination does not work.  I've searched for a few hours, and have tried a few solutions to no avail.  I am trying to get an archive of each of the categories I created under this CPT, am I doing it correctly?  Did something change in the latest version of WordPress that may have affected this?

Here is my code for creating the custom post type:

```
public function gv_game_setup_post_types() {
    $game_labels = array(
        'name'                => 'Games',
        'singular_name'       => 'Game',
        'add_new'             => __('Add New', 'game'),
        'add_new_item'        => __('Add New Game', 'game'),
        'edit_item'           => __('Edit Game', 'game'),
        'new_item'            => __('New Game', 'game'),
        'all_items'           => __('All Games', 'game'),
        'view_item'           => __('View Game', 'game'),
        'search_items'        => __('Search Games', 'game'),
        'not_found'           => __('No Games found', 'game'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __('No Games found in Trash', 'game'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => '',
        'menu_name'           => __('Games', 'game'),
        'exclude_from_search' => false
    );

    $game_args = array(
        'labels'              => $game_labels,
        'public'              => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'supports'            => array('editor', 'title', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies'          => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'rewrite'             => array('slug' => 'game', 'with_front' => false)
    );

    register_post_type('game', $game_args);
}
```

This function is part of a custom plugin I made for this purpose and is being called in the constructor on the 'init' hook.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "the pagination does not work", explain how it's not working.

Comment: Pagination on the archive page is returning a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin to create my custom post types, once it is up and working there is an option to export the php code which you then add to the functions file, then I disable the plugin. For me this is the safest way to ensure that I have it working. And of course you should always visit your permalinks page in the admin after making any changes.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

If you create it correctly you can create a custom post type archive file archive-games.php (this  will be the your custom post type name, eg, something more like this in your functions file,

```
add_action('init', 'cptui_register_my_cpt_game');
function cptui_register_my_cpt_game() {
register_post_type('game', array(
'label' => 'Games',
'description' => '',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'game', 'with_front' => true),
'query_var' => true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes','post-formats'),
'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag'),
'labels' => array (
'name' => 'Games',
'singular_name' => '',
'menu_name' => 'Games',
'add_new' => 'Add Game',
'add_new_item' => 'Add New Game',
'edit' => 'Edit',
'edit_item' => 'Edit Game',
'new_item' => 'New Game',
'view' => 'View Game',
'view_item' => 'View Game',
'search_items' => 'Search Game',
'not_found' => 'No Game Found',
'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Game Found in Trash',
'parent' => 'Parent Game',
)
) ); }
```

And of course ensure you don't have any existing pages with the slug game